# seo friendly url for blogs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

am building a blog system and i have a table a in my database called `url` which save the post title with the date i also have a page called `index.php` with display all the data from database, which when click take you to `post.php`.the problem is that the url is not SEO friendly `site/post?url=seo-friendly-url.html/2017-09-29`,i have a .htaccess file which works well

```
`Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ post.php?url=$1  
RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ post.php?url=$1  
`
```

but refuse to rewrite my blog post,my index hyper link look like this `<a href='post?url=".$row['url']."'>`, have tried to rewrite it to `<a href='post/".$row['url']."'>` but is not working,have made research but still no progress,please any help would be much appreciated,as have been on the issue for some days now.

Comment: I think watching these two videos on YouTube helps you to know the regular methods for handling this situation:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw28-krO7ZM and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgCW2x5QCXo

Answer (score 0):

Add AliasMatch in **VirtualHost** file of your website (This will be located in your apache folder)

These are the lines you need to add in **Virtual host** file

```
AliasMatch ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ post.php?url=$1  
AliasMatch ^post/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ post.php?url=$1
```

In linux based server. The virtual host will be located in the folder

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

Here in this folder find your website virtual host file and add these two lines

Virtual host will have code similar to this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    #Add these two line only donot disturb any other lines 

    AliasMatch ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ post.php?url=$1  
    AliasMatch ^post/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ post.php?url=$1


</VirtualHost>
```

In your .htaccess file **Remove these two lines**

```
RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ post.php?url=$1  
RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ post.php?url=$1
```

---

**Bonus**

Now if you want to redirect the users who are visiting to old url (/post?url="old_url.html") to new seo friendly url (/post/old_url.html) add this to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^post.php?url=([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ post/$1
RewriteRule ^post.php?url=([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ post/$1
```

---

If you have all the lines as comments(# infront of all lines) in virtual host file add this to your virtual host at the bottom

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
        AliasMatch ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ post.php?url=$1  
        AliasMatch ^post/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ post.php?url=$1


    </VirtualHost>
```

**

> Remember to restart your Apache Server after you do the changes

**

Comment: can you share your virtual host file and htaccess file after modification

Comment: `##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>


AliasMatch ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ post.php?url=$1  
AliasMatch ^post/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ post.php?url=$1`

Comment: `Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: I think that is not the exact virtualhost file because it has # before all the lines . **# indicates comments** . One more thing is the AliasMatch code **should be written before </VirtualHost>**

Comment: here is the file directory xampp/apache/conf/extr/httpd-vhosts which is the virtual host

Comment: In Xamp the virtual host file will be located in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: I have updated my answer .. check the bottom of my answer

Comment: I checked it in my system it just worked. Send me all the screen shots of what you modified